# Golang - Can't get array of objects after fetching JSON

Tags: json, go

After I make a request to a server - I get JSON like this:

```
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "class": "...",
      "parameters": [
        { ... }
        { ... }
       ]
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

The type of the variable I've put this data in, is `map[string]interface{}`.

I want to access the `parameters` array in the first object of the `actions` array. I can successfully get the `class` property - `data.(map[string]interface{})["class"]`.

However, if I try the same for the `parameters` property - I get `nil` ...

I tried `data.(map[string][]interface{})["parameters"]` - but I get error `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is map[string]interface {}, not map[string][]interface {}`.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

EDIT:

The Golang code for this is this:

```
func main() {

    var jsonResult map[string]interface{}

    errorFromJsonFetching := utils.GetJSON(theUrl, &jsonResult)
    if errorFromJsonFetching != nil {
      fmt.Printf("Error from checking deploy build: %#v\n", errorFromJsonFetching)
    }

    // get the top level "actions" prop ..
    actionZero := jsonResult["actions"].([]interface{})[0]

    fmt.Printf("Class prop: /%v %T\n", actionZero.(map[string]interface{})["class"], actionZero)
    fmt.Printf("Parameters prop: /%v %T\n", actionZero.(map[string]interface{})["parameters"], actionZero)

}
```

The GetJSON function is from another file in the project:

```
func GetJSON (url string, result interface{}) error {

  fmt.Printf("Getting JSON from %v\n", url)

  resp, err := http.Get(url)

  if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("Cannot fetch URL %q: %v\n", url, err)
  }

  defer resp.Body.Close()

  if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
    return fmt.Errorf("Bad resposne status code: %s\n", resp.Status)
  }

  // attempt to put the JSON in the `result` ..
  err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&result)

  if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("Could not decode the JSON from response, err: %v\n", err)
  }

  return nil;
}
```

EDIT2:

Thanks to the ideas of @larsks in the comments - I created a minimal code sample with JSON in a string, directly in main.go file - and all worked fine.

Then I went ahead to the browser again and tried to fetch the data again - from directly hitting the URL or with `$.getJSON` from a page - and both returned one and the same JSON data.

However, in my Go code, when I dump the JSON data - I see this for the first member of `actions`:

```
map[_class:hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty parameterDefinitions:[map[...
```

So when I try to get the `parameters` array by the key `parameterDefinitions` - then I get the array of object ... :O

Sooooo ... I don't know what's happening ... either Go itself modifies the JSON data when it gets it from the backend, or the backend itself returns different things, depending on how the data is being fetched.

(The backend is the Jenkins API by the way ... so I don't know why I get `parameterDefinitions` instead of `parameters` in Go ... :( ...)

Comment: Your sample data doesn't accurately represent what's returned by the API (there's no `actions` key). Does the data look like `{"actions": [{"class": "...", "parameters": [{...}, {...}]]}` (i.e., the value of `actions` is a list), or `{"actions": {"class": "...", "parameters": {...}}` (i.e., the value is a `map[string]interface{}`)?

Comment: Also your sample data has a `parameters` key, but in your code you're looking for a `properties` key.

Comment: Thanks, @larsks - I checked again and yes, my code sample is a bit incorrect. However - the problem is real :) ... I updated the question with the correct code + sample data I get from the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for updating your question; having the correct data makes it easier to answer.

It's best if the code you include in your question is something we can just grab and run -- that means it compiles and runs, and when given the sample data in your question, it produces the behavior you're asking about.

I've modified your code so that I can run it locally, primarily by replacing the `GetJSON` method with something that reads from a file named `data.json` instead of hitting an API:

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "os"
)

func GetJSON(result interface{}) error {
  datafile, err := os.Open("data.json")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  return json.NewDecoder(datafile).Decode(&result)
}

func main() {
  var jsonResult map[string]interface{}

  errorFromJsonFetching := GetJSON(&jsonResult)
  if errorFromJsonFetching != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error from checking deploy build: %#v\n", errorFromJsonFetching)
  }

  // get the top level "actions" prop ..
  actionZero := jsonResult["actions"].([]interface{})[0]

  fmt.Printf("Class prop: /%v %T\n", actionZero.(map[string]interface{})["class"], actionZero)
  fmt.Printf("Parameters prop: /%v %T\n", actionZero.(map[string]interface{})["parameters"], actionZero)
}
```

If I feed it this sample data, which I believe matches the structure of what you show in your question:

```
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "class": "Name of class",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "alice",
          "color": "blue"
        },
        {
          "name": "bob",
          "count": 10,
        },
        {
          "name": "mallory",
          "valid": false,
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
Class prop: /Name of class map[string]interface {}
Parameters prop: /[map[color:blue name:alice] map[count:10 name:bob] map[name:mallory valid:false]] map[string]interface {}
```

This doesn't produce a `nil` value for the `parameters` key. In order to more fully answer your question, can you update it so that it has sample data and code that reproduces the behavior you're asking baout?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, @larsks ... I was able to retrieve the data, but with another key ... :O ... I left info in the original question, under the `EDIT 2` section.